# Aspect Oriented Programming with Roslyn

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, roslyn

Does roslyn or visual studio 2015 provide API to rewrite IL or "something like that"? Let me explain...

I've read in msdn magazine's article [Use Roslyn to Write a Live Code Analyzer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx%7C), that it is possible to write custom code analyzers **distributed via nuget packages**, without need for visual studio plugins.

I'm really curious, if roslyn compiler and visual studio 2015 will allow to implement e.g. **Code Cotracts** such way, that **no plugin is  required to build it correctly**.

Also, I would like to gain productivity and readability of my code with aspects like [NotifyPropertyChanged] data annotation on properties, but again, if it won't build correctly on every machine with visual studio 2015, it's not a good idea.

Comment: No such feature exists.

Comment: What about Syntax Rewriting? http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2011/10/23/lap-around-roslyn-ctp-syntax-rewriting/ If it was possible to attach custom syntax rewriter to .csproj and run it each time it build, that's all I need

Comment: Yes, but that is not possible.

Comment: You may be interested in Fody, and more specifically in its [PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) add-in.

Comment: You don't need a vs plugin to get a code analyzer / fixer to run in VS.  They can be brought in automatically if specified as part of the project.  There is a project menu item (solution explorer) to add analyzer references to your project.

Comment: @MattWarren: I know I don't need plugin for code analyzer. Did you read the question carefully?

Comment: @liero There is no current Roslyn extension point that would let you manipulate the generated IL. There are only extensions for adding diagnostics or code fixes that rewrite source code.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use DispatchProxy from System.Reflection.DispatchProxy package. Unfortunately I haven't found any examples how to use it, but it looks like a replacement for RealProxy class with some differences (examples how to use RealProxy: [hear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574804.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.returnmessage(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: yes, but this is not what I'm lookig for. It operates at runtime, I was interested in roslyn extensibilty.